# Making the ng-grid cellText from square to round

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have created a plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/VIMTutnu1BzGVfujlhhJ and wanted to see if anyone can throw some pointers to make these cell backgrounds(obviously show up as square) into circles. Basically I am using the ngCellText as shown below:

```
cellTemplate: '<div  title="{{row.entity.EHStatus.TOPPER.desc}}" class="ngCellText"'+ 
                                    'ng-class="{\'green\' : row.getProperty(\'EHStatus.TOPPER.code\') == \'1\' ,\'orange\' : row.getProperty(\'EHStatus.TOPPER.code\') > \'1\',\'red\' : row.getProperty(\'EHStatus.TOPPER.code\') == \'0\',\'yellow\' : row.getProperty(\'EHStatus.TOPPER.code\') < \'0\'}" >&nbsp;</div>'},
```

Are there any good clean ways of achieving this? Please let me know!!

Answer (score 0):

Just give `border-radius: 50%` to all your color classes

Something like this:

```
.green {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: It makes them oval in shape not round little buttons

Comment: I would like to use some sort of button, something that is round